# How to maintain two versions of a project on GitHub?

Tags: git, github, version-control

I have a project on GitHub. I started a new branch on my machine when all my new code goes. I want to be able to keep support the currently stable version. Also, I want all new features to go to the new branch.

Locally, I have two branches `master-dev` and `v2.0`. However, I want to push both branches to GitHub so my code in backed up.

My `master-dev` branch is already on GitHub. I just want to push the new branch `v2.0`.

While in my `v2.0` branch, I did the following

1. git add .
2. git commit -m="Some Message"
3. git push

However, that gave me the following error

> fatal: The current branch v2.0 has no upstream branch. To push the
>   current branch and set the remote as upstream, use

```
git push --set-upstream origin v2.0
```

I don't know what will that command do, I just want to make sure I don't mess up my existing project.

How to maintain both of my branches GitHub?

Comment: It will do what it says: push the current branch and set the remote as upstream. That's what you should do. You know you could read the manual (installed with git), read the git book (freely available online), or even create a playground repo on github and experiment to see what happens.

Comment: what would setting the upstream do?

Comment: It would make git remember that the local 2.0 branch is "linked" to the remote 2.0 branch, so that you can just use git pull/git push to pull and push from/to this remote branch when you're on the 2.0 local branch. Again, read the manual.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the **branches which have already exist in remote**, you can use `git push` or `git push origin branchname`.

But when you **push the new local branch in local which is not exist in remote**, you need to set upstream (tracking branch), you need to set which branch you want push to remote. You can use any of the below commands:

```
git push origin v2.0
git push -u origin v2.0
git push --set-upstream origin v2.0
```

For `git push origin v2.0`, it will create a remote branch v2.0 and push changes in local v2.0 into it.

For `git push -u origin v2.0` and git `push --set-upstream origin v2.0`, they have same function. Both of them create the branch v2.0 in remote and push changes in local v2.0 into it. The difference between the first command is this two commands set the tracking reference between local v2.0 branch and remote v2.0, you can use `git branch –vv` to find the relationship.